# How to run existing EMR serverless job with boto3?

Tags: boto3, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

From boto3 [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr-serverless.html#EMRServerless.Client.start_job_run) for the start_job_run, it seems like I have to create job run every time I want to trigger a job. Does it really have to work that way? Can't I take the ID of the existing job, which has already been defined with all the configuration it needs, and run it?

Reading the doc and searching on the internet

Comment: In addition to the answer, below, Glue may be alternative,  $ aws glue start-job-run --job-name "CSV to CSV" --arguments='--scriptLocation="s3://my_glue/libraries/test_lib.py"'  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html

Comment: You can see an example of using boto3 to run a job here: https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-serverless-samples/tree/main/examples/python-api

If you want to run a job on a regular basis, an orchestrator like Airflow or CloudWatch trigger can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's the way it needs to be executed with boto3. You can call `describe-job-run` to gain the config information and then pass that to `start-job-run`.

This assumes that you have a short lived cluster. Executing jobs on a long lived cluster would be different.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Which function exactly do you mean? I don't see in the API something like describe_job_run

Comment: EMR Serverless changed it to GetJobRun https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr-serverless/latest/APIReference/API_GetJobRun.html

Answer (score 0):

EMR Serverless doesn't have "jobs" or templates (similar to [EMR on EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/job-templates.html)) where you can define all parameters and then reuse them for job runs, but only "job runs" themselves. So yes, you have to specify all parameters every time. You should be able to copy-paste job run config from another job run - use GetJobRun API for that.